# Cracking hash algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography

I am trying to crack a hash algorithm in Java:

```
    public static int encode(String file) {
            int hash = 0;
            file = file.toUpperCase();

            for(int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++) {
                    hash = (hash * 61 + file.charAt(i)) - 32;
            }
            return hash;
    }
```

This is my attempt:

```
public static String decode(int hash) {
            long realHash = (hash < 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE + Math.abs(hash) : hash);
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(50);

            while (realHash > 0) {
                    buffer.put((byte) ((realHash % 61) + 32));
                    realHash = (realHash - 32) / 61;
            }
            buffer.flip();
            return new String(buffer.array()).trim();
    }
```

My solution seems to have severe data loss, I don't think I can fully unhash longer text data due to the overflow of the integer. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't "crack" a hash function in the sense of getting the original data out. You can "crack" it in the sense of getting a hash collision, though.

Comment: Imagine that you could "crack" the hash, and figure out the original text from a single integer, no matter how long the original text has been. Don't you think you'd put these ZIP archive people out of business?..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the integer overflow that's the problem. That's like driving over lava, having your car explode, and concluding that you didn't buy the right kind of gas.

The real problem is that you can't "crack" hash algorithms. There's one big reason why:

## Information Theory

There's a term in information theory known as [Shannon entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). (Fair warning: that article is not easy to get through.) The quick version is that there's a minimum number of bits required to encode any given chunk of information.

[This site](http://www.shannonentropy.netmark.pl/calculate) has a calculator that claims to determine the amount of entropy (i.e. the minimum number of bits) required to losslessly encode a given text. I provided it with this chunk of [artisanal filler text](http://hipsteripsum.me/?paras=1&type=hipster-centric):

> Meggings forage bitters tofu, Wes Anderson food truck craft beer
>   iPhone. Single-origin coffee scenester narwhal, mumblecore mlkshk jean
>   shorts chia trust fund art party pour-over you probably haven't heard
>   of them bitters. Polaroid craft beer Intelligentsia, vinyl Marfa
>   Brooklyn umami.

Assuming `int` is 32 bits on your system, you only have 32 bits of space to encode any given file. But that chunk above -- not too long compared to what I might have used, like War and Peace or the US Code -- requires **1472 bits** at minimum to encode if you want to have any hope of reconstructing the text.

(Commentor [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef) points to [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) ([another good explanation of that concept](http://jeremykun.com/2012/04/21/kolmogorov-complexity-a-primer/)), which is an even better way of representing the information content of a string and the futility of cracking a hash.)

So *information-theoretically* (and leaving aside cheating, like having a pre-filled compression dictionary), it's *impossible* to reconstruct those few (simple handcrafted locally-sourced) sentences from a 32-bit int. It's a basic law of the universe, unfortunately. Ain't gonna happen.

### Practical example, from code

[Another commentor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling) mentions the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) -- the simple idea that, if you have N slots (in this case 2^32), you can't put more than N things in them without putting two or more things in the same slot.

Let's take your hash function:

```
public static int encode(String file) {
        int hash = 0;
        file = file.toUpperCase();

        for(int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++) {
                hash = (hash * 61 + file.charAt(i)) - 32;
        }
        return hash;
}
```

Specifically, this line:

```
file = file.toUpperCase();
```

I want to hash two files:

```
mary had a little lamb

Mary Had A Little Lamb
```

What will their hash values be? Think about it.

(Sidenote: Even with all that said, you *are* overflowing int. :) [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is your friend if you want to do stuff like that.)

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity might be more apt here, since it talks about compressing strings with computer programs.

Comment: You're right! Added a link and credited you.

Comment: I think it's important to add that while you can express 1472 bits using 32, there are many many many other 1472 bit chunks of info that will be compressed into the same 32 bits. Differentiating between them is impossible, so the best you could ever hope for after 'cracking' a hash is to figure out what pathological data set a given key belongs to.

Comment: I probably would've just mentioned the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) - it's a simple and easy to understand principle that gives sufficient evidence that it's impossible to determine the original string of some length greater than the hash, given only the hash.

Comment: Awesome information. Thank you for the detailed and quick response. Much appreciated.